# Symfony2 FormType : Pass custom options into the fieldType

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to pass custom options into my field. Is there a way to set an array of options into my field "code" ?

```
namespace Company\SystemBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class ArbitreType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('code','text',array('required' => true))
            //->add('code','text',array('required' => true,'customOption'=>array('option1'=>'value1')))
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are doing these options? If they are class attributes used to customize you're css, then use the answer provided by @webda21. Otherwise you will have to do something different to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
$builder
    ->add('code', 'text', array(
        'required' => true,
        'attr' => array(
            'option1' => 'value1'
        )
))
```

Comment: Actually, this passes the option in the template and (with the default template) also renders it as HTML-Tag `<input type="text" required="required" option1="value1" />`